# calculate specific rows and populate their result in another field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, python-parser

I'm working on ArcGIS 10 desktop version. I have a file with one entity entered multiple times (rows) and each time that has been given a new value against it. I want to sum the values against this entity and populate it in the new field against same entity. As given in the screenshot, A, BB, BE, C etc needs to be sum separately.

[image]

VB Script and python within field calculator will also work for me.

Comment: I'm finding your use of "against" and "entity" a bit confusing. Can you elaborate or provide a little more detail?

Comment: in the highlighted fields (screenshot), A, B, BE, C,CP etc are entities and 25. 16.66667, 10 etc are values against it. Hope I'm clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

I think I follow what it is that you want to do. If I'm correct you want to summarize your data. I'm sure this is a duplicate but easy enough to explain. See if this does what you want. Right Click the field that has the A, BB, BE etc. and choose "Summarize". Then in the numeric fields of interest choose something like **SUM, AVERAGE, MINIMUM, MAXIMUM** etc. I think this will do what you are asking about. Hope it (and this screenshot) helps.

This will create a separate table. Your questions specifies populating the result in another field which doesn't make a lot of sense to me because the value will be duplicated for each **"entity"**. If that is the desired result, you can join the output table back to the original and add it in (base the tabular join on the field you are calling the "entity". If you save the joined table using Data->Export (right click the layer in the table of contents) it will save the field(s) from the output table in the new copy of your original dataset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the kind effort but this is certainly not what I'm looking for @jbchurchill. take an example for "BE" in first selected field. it is repeating 3 times and value against this is 25. it should give me a sum of 75 for BE.

Comment: Then check the box "Sum" on whatever field that is that has the 25's in it, and that is precisely what you will get.

Comment: No there is some problem. Its about rows not columns. I did as u told me and it gave me a single value in the output dbf. Plus the field (A, B, BB etc) is string it allows me to select "first" and "last" and the field I select with values does not appear in summarize window.

Comment: Thank you its working half for me now. Since populating the field holds priority for me as I need to calculate same way for a number of fields.

Comment: YW - you should be able to summarize multiple fields across the same entity with one run of the "Summarize" tool and then do the join only once! Please accept it (with the green check) if you find this to be the best answer.